# How to detect poll timeout in pyzmq

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, zeromq, pyzmq

```
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

while(1)
    try:
        sockets = dict(poller.poll(timeout)) #How to detect timeout
        # do job
    except SomeTimeoutException:
        break
```

As shown, is there a way to detect when timeout occurs while polling? Couldn't find a way on searching

Answer (score 0):

poll returns tuples with the sockets registered as the first item and a flag denoting whether a frame was received or send. Thus you can just check for the flag, as shown in many pyzmq examples:

```
socket_dict = dict(poller.poll(timeout))
for polled_socket, flag in socket_dict.items():
  if not (flag & zmq.POLLIN):
    print("timeout")
```

If you just need to test one socket, this will work too:

```
if socket.poll(timeout) & zmq.POLLIN:
    print("processing data...")
else:
    print("timeout")
```